# Why my array is of type var int instead of var set of int?

Tags: minizinc

I have the following problem: I want to call the global constraint **at_most** but I got an error related to the signature

```
constraint forall(i in 0..w-1)(at_most(l_max, [board[i,j] | j in 0..l_max-1], 0..n));
```

the second argument does not match because it turns out to be var int instead of var set of int but I have previously defined board in this way:

```
set of int: VALUES = 0..n;
array[0..w-1,0..l_max-1] of var VALUES: board;
```

Comment: Exactly what error do you got? It would help if you show the full model (or rather as small as possible subset of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a general message: `at_most` is among the list of deprecated constraints: https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.5/en/lib-globals.html#deprecated-constraints.
Instead, you should use a `count` constraint. These constraints are more flexible and better supported by the solvers.

In this case there seems to be a misconception about what `at_most` does. At most only restrict the number of time a single value occurs. You are. however, giving it a full set of values.

If you are counting all the different values, then you instead can use [`global_cardinality_low_up`](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.5/en/lib-globals.html#index-27). (You might also want to look at the closed version).
I think you meant to write the following constraint.

```
constraint forall(i in 0..w-1)(
  global_cardinality_low_up([board[i,j] | j in 0..l_max-1], 0..n, [0 | i in 0..n], [l_max | i in 0..n])
);
```

This constraint insure that for the comprehensions the values in `0..n` only occur `l_max` times.

Note that if you are using the comprehension to select a full row, then it would be better to use slice notation: `board[i,..]`.